# Have the linter recognize the type "Ref <T>" as "T" instead of "ObjectId"

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, mongoose-populate, typegoose

When I have a class like the following:

```
export class Application{
    @prop({ required: [true, 'app name is required'], unique: true })
    name!: string;

    @prop({ required: [true, 'component is required'], ref: Component})
    component!: Ref<Component>;
}
```

And assuming that the 'Component' class has a 'name' property, I can't do this:

```
let app: Application
const appName = 'appTest';
app = await (await this.findOne({ name: appName })).populate('component').execPopulate();
console.log(app.component.name);
```

because it gives me the following error:

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Ref<Component, ObjectId>'.
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'ObjectId'
```

Is there a way I can have the linter perceive the type as T (from `Ref<T>`) rather than ObjectId?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, what worked quite well for me is to use type guards, specifically the [isDocument and isDocumentArray](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/functions/typeguards/isDocument/) from Typegoose.
It would be something like this:

```
let app: Application
const appName = 'appTest';
app = await (await this.findOne({ name: appName })).populate('component').execPopulate();
if (isDocument(app.component)) {
console.log(app.component.name);
}
```